# How can I display the sheet contents in a PDF for a given range, from a shared google sheets document using URL parameters?

Tags: google-sheets

In a publically shared document I have url like:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jK0It26SFeIS_JPEjkEUH7IEcJLxz6JXVBxuUy2mSa0/preview?ouptut=pdf

The parameter `?output=pdf` does not do anything. Also, if I use the range parameter to say display A1:C5 by using `?range=A1:C5` it does not do anything, the entire sheet displays ignoring the request.

Questions:

1-How can I display the sheet contents in a PDF for a given range, from a shared google sheets document using URL parameters?

2-What does edit#gid=0 mean? Does it mean "show first tab"?

3-Are parameter names case sensitive?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try in html as follows (or json)

```
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jK0It26SFeIS_JPEjkEUH7IEcJLxz6JXVBxuUy2mSa0/gviz/tq?tqx=out:html&sheet=MainIndexTab&range=A13:C18&tq=SELECT+A%2CB%2CC
```

[image]

edit

you can do as follows to retrieve a pdf for a given range

```
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jK0It26SFeIS_JPEjkEUH7IEcJLxz6JXVBxuUy2mSa0/export?format=pdf&range=A13:C18&gid=0
```

Comment: The idea of using SELECT in the URL is brilliant. Thanks.

Comment: I have added a new answer for pdf

Answer (score 1):

Not sure that it can be displayed as a PDF, however if you want to allow people to download it in PDF file try this:

[https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jK0It26SFeIS_JPEjkEUH7IEcJLxz6JXVBxuUy2mSa0/export?format=pdf&embedded=true](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/130654/all-google-docs-url-parameters-functions-commands)

That should allow the spreadsheet to be downloaded as a PDF.

References:

- [Unofficial Google Sheets parameters.](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/130654/all-google-docs-url-parameters-functions-commands)

Comment: Thanks for your answer and the link. Still this did not solve my problem!